# I cant add a dollar sign after the formatted number (Java)

Tags: java, formatting

I cant seem to figure out why this code keeps giving me errors related to formatting when i try to reduce the numbers to the second decimal point, while also adding a "**$**" after them.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int months = scan.nextInt();
int waterPrice = 20;
int internetPrice = 15;
int water = months * waterPrice;
int internet = months * internetPrice;
double others = 0;
double electricity = 0;
double electricityPrice;

for(int i=0; i<months; i++){
    electricityPrice = scan.nextDouble();
    electricity += electricityPrice;
    others = (electricity + water + internet) + 0.2 * (electricity + water + internet);

}
double avarage = (electricity + water + internet + others)/5;

System.out.println("Electricity: %.2f$$"+ electricity);
System.out.printf("Water: %.2d$$", water);
System.out.printf("Internet: %.2d$$", internet);
System.out.printf("Other: %.2f$$", others);
System.out.printf("Average: %.2f$$", avarage);
```

Comment: I suggest you strip this down the least code needed to show problem. And report exact error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
System.out.format("Electricity: %.2f $$\n", 234.5554);
```

or

```
System.out.printf("Electricity: %.2f $$\n", 234.5554);
```

**Output:**

[image]

In your case:

```
System.out.printf("Electricity: %.2f$$\n", electricity);
System.out.printf("Water: %d$$\n", water);
System.out.printf("Internet: %d$$\n", internet);
System.out.printf("Other: %.2f$$\n", others);
System.out.printf("Average: %.2f$$\n", avarage);
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** In your case I have replaced `%.2d` with `%d` because `water` and `internet` are of `integer` type. If you want decimal precision for all i.e. `100.00 $$` then you need to replace `int` with `double` and use `System.out.printf(%.2f$$\n)`

Comment: You need to add `\n` at the end in order to move the cursor to a new line. Else you will get everything printed out on same line. `System.out.printf("Electricity: %.2f $$\n", 234.5554);`

Comment: No, i need to have 100.00 $, not 100 $ for water and internet

Comment: @MickeyMoise just use %.2f$$ as mentioned above

Comment: @MickeyMoise in that case you need to change type of water and internet to double and use %.2f$$. It is always a good practice to use a similar type of data in such type of application development. Hope it works for you. Let me know if you encounter problem.

Comment: @Dcoder only using %.2f$$ won't work. It will throw an exception. The data type of water and internet also need to be changed

Comment: @MickeyMoise I have update the note part in my answer. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `System.out.println()` which is not useful for formatted output. it will concatenate output to single string and display it.

For formatted output like you want go with `Syatem.out.printf()` which is similar to **C printf()** function.

You can also use `String.format()` for formatted output.

Example:

```
Syatem.out.printf("Electricity: %.2f$$", electricity)
System.out.println("Electricity: " + String.format("%.2f$$", electricity))
```

Comment: Why would you do the second one, though? (Also, you probably want a `%n` on the end of the first)